# How to alter bokeh.charts axis label size?

Tags: python, data-visualization, jupyter, bokeh

I'm using Bokeh 0.11.1, and `pip install --upgrade bokeh` reports that I'm using the latest version.

I can determine how to change bokeh x-axis text size parameters if using bokeh.plotting, but not in bokeh charts.  The code below, if run in a Jupyter notebook, will show very tight x-axis labels.  I'd like the font to be smaller -- any tips on how to accomplish this?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pm0kjp/datastore/master/river_data.csv")

import bokeh.charts
import bokeh.plotting
bokeh.plotting.output_notebook()

tooltips=[
    ('Water Site ', '$x'),
    ('Average of Enterococcus Count ', '$y')
]

p = bokeh.charts.Scatter(data, x='Site', y='EnteroCount', 
        title="Swimming Holes By Average Enterococcus Count", ylabel="Enterococcus Count", tooltips=tooltips)
p.width=1000
bokeh.charts.show(p)
```

Documentation would suggest that I could simply add 
`p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "8pt"`, but if I do that I get the error 
`AttributeError: 'Chart' object has no attribute 'yaxis'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an entire user's guide section dedicated to [styling visual properties](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html), including how to style [axis labels](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#labels). Since plots created by `bokeh.charts` and `bokeh.plotting` both resolve to the same set of low level objects, setting the properties is identical in either case:

```
p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "8pt"
```

Here is a complete working example for `0.12.3`:

```
In [1]: import bokeh

In [2]: bokeh.__version__
Out[2]: '0.12.3'

In [3]: import pandas as pd
   ...: data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pm0kjp/datastore/master/river_data.csv")
   ...:

In [4]: import bokeh.charts

In [5]: tooltips=[
   ...:     ('Water Site ', '$x'),
   ...:     ('Average of Enterococcus Count ', '$y')
   ...: ]
   ...: p = bokeh.charts.Scatter(data, x='Site', y='EnteroCount',
   ...:         title="Swimming Holes By Average Enterococcus Count", ylabel="Enterococcus Count", tooltips=tooltips)
   ...: p.width=1000
   ...:

In [6]: p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "4pt"

In [7]: bokeh.charts.output_file("/tmp/chart.html")

In [8]: bokeh.charts.show(p)
```

And here is the result, with tiny y-axis label:

[image]

---

If you can't update to version `0.12` for some reason, you can do:

```
In [12]: from bokeh.models import Axis

In [13]: p.select(type=Axis)
Out[13]:
[LinearAxis(id='54b21a9f-22e0-4f7a-b809-8d4f755a444e', ...),
 CategoricalAxis(id='b52e7b2c-2b18-4578-be42-4fbfba17af60', ...)]
```

get ahold of all the axes objects, which you can modify directly by setting their `axis_label_text_font_size` property. But you'll have to figure out which axis is x and which is y.

Comment: When I try that I get `AttributeError: 'Chart' object has no attribute 'yaxis'`.  I will edit the question to show that I already tried that!

Comment: Then you have a fairly old version of Bokeh. This is why it is *always important* to state what version for software you are using when asking for help. My first suggestion is simply to update to a newer version.

Comment: OK, I'm on the latest bokeh that pip can install, and still see the problem.  I've edited the question.

Comment: Then you have some installation or environment or other problem particular to your system. I've updated the answer above with a complete notebook session as well as the output, for Bokeh `0.12.3` which is currently the latest released version, available via pip or conda.

Comment: I've also updated the answer in case you mean that you are not permitted to update to Bokeh >= `0.12`

Comment: Thanks, all, I was *wrong* about not being able to version up -- I had updated Bokeh while still in my notebook.  Once I restarted the notebook server, all was well!